# ILOG CPLEX Overflow occurred

Tags: cplex

When I run my CPLEX model, under the Profiler tab I get the error

`Overflow occurred, please use oplrun -profile.`

How do I setup oplrun? I looked at the IBM website but I don't understand the instruction. Can someone show an example of setting up an oplrun that includes a .mod and .dat file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you may either call [oplrun from the IDE](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/icos/20.1.0?topic=interface-executing-oplrun-from-ide) or in the [command line](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/icos/20.1.0?topic=interface-executing-oplrun-manually).

Comment: How do I do it on Macbook?